# Linker error LNK1120 followed by LNK2001

Tags: c++, dll, mfc, linker, dllexport

I've a `MFC` `Dll` from where I'm trying to export certain functions.
These functions have been exported in the form :

```
BOOL WINAPI ProcessIdle();
BOOL WINAPI someFunc();
```

- in the header file and the implementation in the `.cpp` file.

**Header File**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif  /* __cplusplus */

BOOL WINAPI CreateDialoge(HWND hWndParent);
BOOL WINAPI FilterDllMsg(LPMSG lpMsg);
void WINAPI ProcessDllIdle();
BOOL WINAPI someFunc();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**.def File**

```
EXPORTS
    ; Explicit exports can go here
    CreateDialoge                @2
    FilterDllMsg                 @4
    ProcessDllIdle               @5
    someFunc                     @6
```

These functions have also been defined in the .def file

When the `DLL` is created, I can see via `dependencyWalker` that the function, `someFunc()`, is indeed being exported.

Unfortunately, my application, where I'm trying to reference the function, reports a LNK1120 followed by LNK2001 error.

I do not understand, because another exported function, `ProcessIdle()`, works fine, my own function, `someFunc()`, does not.

I've tried replacing the call, `WINAPI`,with `_stdcall`, and even `__declspec (dllexport)`, but to no avail.

Kindly advise.

Comment: That linker error doesn't have anything to do with what the DLL looks like.  Only the *import library* of the DLL matters.  With the most obvious explanation that you simply are forgetting to tell the linker about it.

Comment: Please post the exact error from the linker.

Comment: `LNK2001` is usually paired with `LNK1120`. Both errors indicate that you have a missing external symbol. This usually means one of (a) the symbol is not properly exported, (b) the symbol is not declared with the correct linkage, (c) the symbol is used from both C and C++ code without `extern "C"`, (d) the library or object file containing the implementation is not supplied to the linker, or (e) there is no implementation for the symbol at all.

Comment: Posted the code in the header file which exports the functions. 
 
`Error LNK2001 : Unresolved external symbol _someFunc@0 ` is the linker error.